# PHP MySQL associative array using array_push

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

I'm trying to create a associative array using PHP. I'm using a ajax script that calls a json file.

I have tested the script using the following PHP code:

```
$testLocs = array(
'loc5' => array( 'info' => 'Some random info', 'lat' => 0, 'lng' => 60 ),
'loc6' => array( 'info' => 'Some random info', 'lat' => 0, 'lng' => 40.345 )
);
echo json_encode($testLocs);
```

which echos:

```
{"loc1":{"info":"Some random info","lat":0,"lng":60},"loc1":{"info":"Some random info","lat":0,"lng":40.345}}
```

The ajax code will work correctly. Now I'm trying to write a PHP script that will get the info from the database. My PHP code is below

```
$query = "Select * from table";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$json_data = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$id = $row['id'];
$lat = $row['lat'];
$lon = $row['lon'];
$page = $row['page'];
array_push($json_data, array('info' => 'Some random info', 'lat' => $lat, 'lng' => $lon)); 
}


echo json_encode($json_data);
```

which echos:

```
{"info":"Some random info","lat":"-31.9522","lng":"115.8614"},{"info":"Some random info","lat":"40.7842","lng":"-73.8422"}
```

I cannot figure out how to put `'loc' =>` in front of each array. The ajax is using The locNUM as a unique ID.

Thank you

Comment: Change **`mysql_*`** to `mysqli` or `PDO`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$json_data = array();
$i = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$id = $row['id'];
$lat = $row['lat'];
$lon = $row['lon'];
$page = $row['page'];
$json_data["loc" . ($i++)] = array('info' => 'Some random info', 'lat' => $lat, 'lng' => $lon); 
}
```

instead of `array_push`.
`array_push` is meant as a pure array function, not as a hash manipulating function.

Comment: Thank you it works now. I seen a tutorial how to do it but then I had arrays inside arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If `$row['id']` is the unique ID for locNUM:

```
$json_data["loc".$id] = array('info' => 'Some random info', 'lat' => $lat, 'lng' => $lon)
```

[`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) is the same as `$array[] = $var;`, which gives you an incremented numeric key.